# How to SELECT MIN( ) in SQL with also selecting some other fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `actor` table inside my `Movie_Info` database which contains `Actor_Name`, `Birth_Year`, `No_Of_Films`, `No_Of_Awards` etc fields.

Now I need to **find the name, current age, number of films and number of awards of the youngest actor**.

I tried with:

```
SELECT
        MIN(
            YEAR(
                SYSDATE( )
            ) - Birth_Year
        ) AS age
        ,Actor_name
        ,No_Of_Films
        ,No_Of_Awards
    FROM
        actor
;
```

But unfortunately, it always gives the 1st entry/row of the table. How can I fix it?

Comment: please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM actor a
ORDER BY Birth_Year DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  If there are multiple youngest actors with the same birth year, then you will arbitrarily get one of them.  That is consistent with your question (which asks for "actor" not "actors").

If you want all of them, then one method is a subquery to get the most recent birth year:

```
select a.*
from actor a
where a.birth_year = (select max(a2.birth_year) from actor a2);
```

Answer (score 2):

A table in MySQL is record based.

The results of a query are record based too, because they can be used as input for another query.

If you use a function like `MIN()` then MySQL would like to know from which column it need to get the minimum value, but also to what group that item belongs.

You are not using `GROUP BY`, therefore MySQL will consider the complete table as 1 group, then you are asking the `MIN(...)` value of something, which can only be 1 (one) value. This leaves you with 1 (one) record.